# sentence transformer using huggingface/transformers pre-trained model vs SentenceTransformer

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model, sentence-transformers

[This](https://www.sbert.net/examples/training/sts/README.html) page has two scripts

When should one use 1st method shown below vs 2nd? As `nli-distilroberta-base-v2` trained specially for finding sentence embedding wont that always be better than the first method?

`training_stsbenchmark.py1`  -

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer,  LoggingHandler, losses, models, util
#You can specify any huggingface/transformers pre-trained model here, for example, bert-base-uncased, roberta-base, xlm-roberta-base
model_name = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 'distilbert-base-uncased'

# Use Huggingface/transformers model (like BERT, RoBERTa, XLNet, XLM-R) for mapping tokens to embeddings
word_embedding_model = models.Transformer(model_name)

# Apply mean pooling to get one fixed sized sentence vector
pooling_model = models.Pooling(word_embedding_model.get_word_embedding_dimension(),
                               pooling_mode_mean_tokens=True,
                               pooling_mode_cls_token=False,
                               pooling_mode_max_tokens=False)

model = SentenceTransformer(modules=[word_embedding_model, pooling_model])
```

`training_stsbenchmark_continue_training.py` -

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, LoggingHandler, losses, util, InputExample
model_name = 'nli-distilroberta-base-v2'
model = SentenceTransformer(model_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing 2 different things:

`training_stsbenchmark.py` - This example shows how to **create a SentenceTransformer** model **from scratch** by using a pre-trained transformer model together with a pooling layer.

In other words, you are creating your own model `SentenceTransformer` using **your own data**, therefore fine-tuning.

`training_stsbenchmark_continue_training.py` - This example shows **how to continue** training on STS data for a **previously created & trained** `SentenceTransformer` model.

In that example, they load a model trained on NLI data.

So, to answer "wont that always be better than the first method?"

> It depends on you final results. Try both methods and check for yourself which will deliver better cross-validation results.